# Azure DevOps wiki .attachments folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-wiki

is there a way to browse ".attachments" folder from the Azure DevOps wiki page?

I insert images, later want to check folder content but not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just fin the way to browse this folder.
The wiki create a repository not visible in the repos list. you can browse it with this url:

https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganisation/MyProject/_git/MyProject.wiki

Comment: I can't accept my own response. The response is verifio, you can accept if you want

Comment: Is there a way to see it from azure wiki as well? That can dynamically show files that are added to a directory in GIT repo

Answer (score 1):

One solution that worked for me is to clone the wiki repo, then you can delete or edit the file in .attachments, commit/push via git.

See also:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-file-structure?view=azure-devops